# IIS web socket proxy encoding issue

Tags: iis, websocket, proxy

I am using IIS as a web-socket proxy server. Web-socket requests get forwarded to a different tomcat server. This configuration is completed via a connector between the two and we define properties like **filters, isapi_redirect.properties and workers.properties**.
Any file hosted on IIS webroot which passes the filter criteria, gets processed via tomcat server.

The same web-socket file, when running on the server directly, returns proper echo response.  Eg- **sdfd©** returns **sdfd©**.
When above mentioned file is hosted on IIS instead, then request for **sdfd©** returns **sdfd?**

Steps tried so far -

1. Set up encoding in web.config - **configuration->system.web->globalization** to utf-8
2. Changed runtime .NET version from v2 to v4.

Finally, set up wireshark to inspect packets -
Data packet from browser to websocket connection (IIS configured port) shows correct data.

```
0000   7b 22 6e 73 22 3a 22 63 6f 6c 64 66 75 73 69 6f   {"ns":"coldfusio
0010   6e 2e 77 65 62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 2e 63 68 61 6e   n.websocket.chan
0020   6e 65 6c 73 22 2c 22 74 79 70 65 22 3a 22 70 75   nels","type":"pu
0030   62 6c 69 73 68 22 2c 22 63 68 61 6e 6e 65 6c 22   blish","channel"
0040   3a 22 73 74 6f 63 6b 73 22 2c 22 64 61 74 61 22   :"stocks","data"
0050   3a 22 73 64 66 64 c2 a9 22 2c 22 61 70 70 4e 61   :"sdfd..","appNa
0060   6d 65 22 3a 22 77 65 62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 73 61   me":"websocketsa
0070   6d 70 6c 65 61 70 70 33 22 7d                     mpleapp3"}
```

When IIS sends this data to websocket listener via TCP port, it replaces © with ?

```
0000   02 00 00 00 45 02 00 cc 5e 6d 40 00 80 06 00 00   ....E...^m@.....
0010   7f 00 00 01 7f 00 00 01 c8 8f 21 89 08 1b ec 28   ..........!....(
0020   1e 12 d8 2b 50 18 20 fa 31 22 00 00 31 36 30 3b   ...+P. .1"..160;
0030   32 3b 63 65 31 38 36 65 34 30 2d 34 30 62 64 2d   2;ce186e40-40bd-
0040   34 65 36 66 2d 39 65 62 30 2d 64 31 36 65 37 63   4e6f-9eb0-d16e7c
0050   64 62 65 33 34 61 3b 7b 22 6e 73 22 3a 22 63 6f   dbe34a;{"ns":"co
0060   6c 64 66 75 73 69 6f 6e 2e 77 65 62 73 6f 63 6b   ldfusion.websock
0070   65 74 2e 63 68 61 6e 6e 65 6c 73 22 2c 22 74 79   et.channels","ty
0080   70 65 22 3a 22 70 75 62 6c 69 73 68 22 2c 22 63   pe":"publish","c
0090   68 61 6e 6e 65 6c 22 3a 22 73 74 6f 63 6b 73 22   hannel":"stocks"
00a0   2c 22 64 61 74 61 22 3a 22 73 64 66 64 3f 22 2c   ,"data":"sdfd?",
00b0   22 61 70 70 4e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 77 65 62 73 6f   "appName":"webso
00c0   63 6b 65 74 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 61 70 70 33 22 7d   cketsampleapp3"}
```